# How to split array with 1 column into multiple columns (numpy array)

Tags: arrays, numpy, split, multiple-columns, columnsorting

I currently have a .txt file that has been loaded into python as a list, and then placed into a np array as a single column with n number of rows depending on the file size. The file has rows trimmed off the top and bottom to clean it up. Relevant code is shown below:

```
# Open the .txt file in the user selected folder

txtFile = glob.glob(folderView + "**/*.txt", recursive = True)
print (" The text files in the folder " + userInput + " are: " + str(txtFile))
# The quantitative output epatemp.txt file is always index position 1 in the glob list.
epaTemp = txtFile[1]
print (epaTemp)

###

quantData = open(epaTemp, 'r')
print (quantData)
result = [line.split(',') for line in quantData.readlines()[24:]]
print (result)
n = 4
result = result[:-n or None]
print (result)
print (" Length of List: " + str(len(result)))
print (result[0])

### Loop through all list components and split each
print (" NUMPY STUFF! ")
list_array = np.array(result)
print (list_array)
```

The array is then printed like this: much cleaner than the 1990's .txt files I am given to process...

[image: Numpy_Array_Print]

My issue is that I am unable to split this single column into multiple columns after defining the opened file as a numpy array in the final lines of code listed above. I am trying to produce a single column for everything that is separated by a space, `" "`, but am having trouble doing so. It might also be important to note that when I use `numpy.shape(list_array)`, it returns nothing as if the array is not being interpreted properly. The overall goal is to turn this 1col x *n*-rows array into 7col x *n*-rows for every value split by a `" "` in the text file. If anyone can help me with this issue I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Numpy is not made for text processing. So turn it back into a list of strings. Split each string. You get a list of lists. Turn that back into numpy (2D). Then use transpose to access columns rather than rows. Also I'd use `pandas`, which can recognize a list of rows as a dataframe in a single line.

Comment: Go back to the `result` line.  Is `line.split(',')` right?  Are columns of really divided by commas.  Your array display suggests not.  `line.split()` uses the default 'white-space' split.  It might help if you showed part of the original file.  It might be a valid `csv` file (using the right delimiter).

Comment: I think you both are correct. I am am making the mistake of splitting either in pandas or numpy rather than before (I've tried both). I tested the file in Excel and when split by "space" the text file opens perfectly. I believe this is the issue, I'll make the changes. I appreciate the help. I'm relatively new to python, learning it for my workflow so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed. I did split the txt file incorrectly, Using `line.split()` solved the issue. `pandas` was also necessary, as this was not the best application for np. Thanks everyone for the feedback.